# How to get a creation date when an item was added to a table view by clicking a button using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a to do list app and I'm trying to get the current date so when a button is clicked and the item is added to the table view I get the date. The date is being displayed on detailTextLaber but whenever I add a new item the date automatically changes on all the items, so it basically becomes the current date again, how can I make it not to update on the other items?
[Here's an image of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ukVY.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question, as asked, is too vague. Post your current code, including the data model you use to represent your list items. Any help we offer would likely be too abstract to be useful otherwise.

Comment: @DuncanC Hey mate sorry I'm really new to this, here's the other .swift file, that's all I use: [link](http://imgur.com/8mdRjzg)

Comment: Please include your code in your question, **not** as images.

Comment: @JanGreve Here you go: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let date = NSDate()
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        formatter.stringFromDate(date)
        let myCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        myCell.textLabel?.text = itemList[indexPath.row]
        myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(date)"
        if ((myCell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(date)") != nil) {
        }
        return myCell
    }`

Comment: Doni, did you see how ugly that looks? Please delete the comment and use the edit button to edit your question.

Comment: @JanGreve truly sorry, I'm also new here. :/

Comment: See the edit button under your question. Click it, edit your question, and add the code using code tags (the braces in the editing tools). It should format correctly, including indentation. If it doesn't look right when you save your edits you can go back and fine-tune it until it's readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the date in the models (in the itemlist or the item), not generate new dates in `cellForIndexPath`.

Comment: Not having access to your code since you only provided images, I do not know about your `itemList` definition. But there is so much more wrong w/ your code. You are not reusing cells, you are not reusing the date formatter, you are reloading all data on removal rather than just deleting the corresponding cell, for example. You should invest more reseach and maybe read a tutorial or two.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at apple's Master/Detail template in Xcode
. The date should be created in the button action, i.e. when
 is clicked and the item is added. TableView cells are reused so CellForRowAtIndexPath will not work. I hope that this helps.